# Let vs. Binding in Clojure

Tags: binding, clojure, let

I understand that they're different since one works for setting `*compile-path*` and one doesn't. However, I need help with why they're different.

`let` creates a new scope with the given bindings, but `binding`...?

Answer (score 112, accepted):

`let` creates a lexically scoped immutable alias for some value.  `binding` creates a dynamically scoped binding for some `Var`.

Dynamic binding means that the code inside your `binding` form and any code which that code calls (even if not in the local lexical scope) will see the new binding.

Given:

```
user> (def ^:dynamic x 0)
#'user/x
```

`binding` actually creates a dynamic binding for a `Var` but `let` only shadows the var with a local alias:

```
user> (binding [x 1] (var-get #'x))
1
user> (let [x 1] (var-get #'x))
0
```

`binding` can use qualified names (since it operates on `Var`s) and `let` can't:

```
user> (binding [user/x 1] (var-get #'x))
1
user> (let [user/x 1] (var-get #'x))
; Evaluation aborted.
;; Can't let qualified name: user/x
```

`let`-introduced bindings are not mutable.  `binding`-introduced bindings are thread-locally mutable:

```
user> (binding [x 1] (set! x 2) x)
2
user> (let [x 1] (set! x 2) x)
; Evaluation aborted.
;; Invalid assignment target
```

Lexical vs. dynamic binding:

```
user> (defn foo [] (println x))
#'user/foo
user> (binding [x 1] (foo))
1
nil
user> (let [x 1] (foo))
0
nil
```

See also [Vars](http://clojure.org/vars), [let](http://clojure.org/special_forms#let).

Comment: This plus http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(programming)#Static_versus_dynamic_scoping really advanced my understanding. Thank you sir!

Comment: The x must be bound with the ^:dynamic hint to not throw an error, i beleave.

Answer (score 13):

One more syntactic difference for let vs binding:

For binding, all the initial values are evaluated before any of them are bound to the vars.  This is different from let, where you can use the value of a previous "alias" in a subsequent definition.

```
user=>(let [x 1 y (+ x 1)] (println y))
2
nil

user=>(def y 0)
user=>(binding [x 1 y (+ x 1)] (println y))
1
nil
```

Comment: You need ^:dynamic to define x to 0 (also dynamically) to make your second example work.

Answer (score 9):

`binding` binds a value to a name in the per-thread global environment

As you mentioned, `let` creates a new scope for said bindings.