# How to test session state with Ring?

Tags: clojure, ring, noir

I'm trying out Clojure web development with Ring + Compojure + lib-noir, and I can't figure out how to test the session state.

Comment: by "test the session state" you mean creating unit tests or just peeking at the contents of the current session?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just mimic the style used for the actual session tests in ring: https://github.com/ring-clojure/ring/blob/master/ring-core/test/ring/middleware/session/test/cookie.clj.

Just create a cookie-store, and then read/write to it, and assert the handlers respond accordingly. Given you are also using lib-noir, perhaps this example is more appropriate: https://github.com/noir-clojure/lib-noir/blob/master/test/noir/session_test.clj.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean for unit tests, you can use `binding`, which will create new bindings for the vars.

You can check a good explanation that can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1523385/987447).

A sample unit tests with `lib-noir`

```
(ns your.test.core
  (:use [clojure.test])
  (:require [noir.session :as s]))


(binding [s/*noir-session* (atom {})]
  ; store new sessions
  (s/put! "xxxx" {:value "1234"})
  (s/put! "my_session" {:value "abcdefg"})

  ; run tests
  (is (= {:value "1234"} (s/get "xxxx")))
  (is (= {:value "abcdefg"} (s/get "my_session"))))
```

You can check the [source code](https://github.com/noir-clojure/lib-noir/blob/master/src/noir/session.clj) of `noir.session` here.